# Compose a groupby record with avg in Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL query: 
`SELECT *, AVG(value) as avg FROM users_has_project GROUP BY project_id`
And I have translated in Eloquent in the following way:

```
Vote::select('AVG(value) as avg')->groupBy('project_id')->get();
```

But I received the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AVG(value)' in
>   'field list' (SQL: select `AVG(value)` as `avg` from
>   `users_has_project` group by `project_id`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a raw query for the aggregate:

```
Vote::selectRaw('AVG(value) as avg')->groupBy('project_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a tiny enhancement in @DigitalDrifter's answer:

```
Vote::selectRaw('project_id, AVG(value) as avg')->groupBy('project_id')->get();
```